# How to Cache API data using AsyncStorage React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, caching, react-native, redux

Fairly new to React native and its concepts. I have been playing with RN for a while to create an application to fetch API data from

*http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos*

I have been looking into the documentation of AsyncStorage to implement how i can cache the API data so that upon terminating the application, it doesn't have to deal with fetching the data from web again and again, but wasn't successfully able to implement it.

It will be great if you can provide me help/suggestion based on it. I have included my source code for the 2 important files in my application, along with the a *Test.js* file with how i was trying to achieve.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, Text, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import GalleryDetail from './GalleryDetail';

class GalleryList extends Component {

state = { photos: []};

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then(response => this.setState({ photos: response.data }))
    .catch((error)=> console.warn("fetch Error: ", error));
}

getPhotos = async()=> {
    try {
        photos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

savePhotos(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem('GalleryPhotos', this.state.photos);
    console.log('works !');
}

renderPhoto = ({item})=> {
    return <GalleryDetail photo={item}/>
}

keyExtractor = (photo, index) => photo.id;

render () {

    if(!this.state.photos){
        return <ActivityIndicator/>;
    }

    return (
            <FlatList
                data = {this.state.photos}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this.renderPhoto}
            />
    );
}
}

export default GalleryList;
```

and GalleryDetail linked with GalleryList-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
 import Card from './Card';
 import CardSection from './CardSection';

const GalleryDetail = (props)=> {
     return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection style = {styles.headerContentStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.thumbnailStyle}
                    source = {{ uri: props.photo.thumbnailUrl}}/>
                <Text style= {styles.textStyle}>{props.photo.title}    </Text>
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
};

const styles = {
   headerContentStyle: {
       flexDirection: 'column',
       justifyContent: 'space-around'
   },

   thumbnailStyle: {
       height: 60,
       width: 60
   },

   textStyle: {
       fontSize: 12,
       //textAlign: 'right',
       flexDirection: 'row',
       justifyContent: 'flex-end',
       flex: 1,
       flexWrap: 'wrap',
       marginLeft: 5,
       marginRight: 5,
    }
    }

    export default GalleryDetail;
```

My method of trying was that-
Upon launching the application, it will first look in asyncStorage, if it finds the data- it fetches from async otherwise going to the web,fetching and storing again for later use. 
I tried to implement somewhat like this in a separate file since i dint wanted to breakdown my already running app. The weird broken syntax is

```
State = {
        photos: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        // just a variable acting to fetch data from the stored keyvalue pair

        check = AsyncStorage.getItem("PhotosKey").then((response) => {
                     this.setState({"PhotosKey": response});
                      }).done();

        if(check) {
            console.log('Data was fetched!!!!!');
            check();
        }

        else {
            console.log("Data was not fetched!");

            var Data = axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').
            then(response => this.setState({ photos: response.data })).
            catch((error)=> console.warn("fetch Error: ", error));



        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const photoStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos')
    if(photoStorage) {
      try {
        const photoResp = await axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
        const photoData = await JSON.stringify(photoResp.data)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('GalleryPhotos', photoData);
      } catch(e) {
        console.warn("fetch Error: ", error)
     }
    .then(response => this.setState({ photos: response.data }))
   }
 }
```

later

```
getPhotos = async()=> {
  try {
      photos = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos'));
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Subramanya for your help. It gave me a really good perception of how my code will look like. I just have few concerns to share. My motive to add asyncstorage inside React native is so, upon starting the application, it should fetch data from GalleryPhotos if it wasnt able to find, it will fetch data and then store it for next use. The code your wrote i believe is more like- fetching and storing the data every single time. Since the data is same everytime, it doesnt requires to fetch everytime. Please correct me if im missing something. :)

Comment: @Rex- Thanks so much for your code. I will totally look into this code when updating my application after implementing Redux. But thanks so much for your time. I believe it took a lot of your time to answer my question (being so lengthy )

Comment: I have updated answer based on your comment, I added a check with if condition, whether GalleryPhotos exists or not and then make api call, hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

The approach from `Subramanya` is basically all you need to get started, I'm just going to introduce a state management approach with `redux-persist` where you can definitely appreciate when your app grows.

> [Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) is performant, easy to implement, and easy to extend.

Let say you have your app hooked up with `redux` and implemented a fairly organised state tree, `redux-persist` stores the entire app state with `AsyncStorage` or any storage engine of your choice.

For instance, let's assume that your API endpoint returns a collection of photos, all you need to do is update the store, and your users can expect their data is safe and saved with `redux-persist`.

**I have not tested all the code below**

Let's define the `store` first,

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, } from "redux";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

import reducers from "../reducers"

const middleWare = [ReduxThunk]

const store = createStore(
  reducers, 
  {},
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
)

// you can define more parameters, like blacklist or whitelist a reducer
// also, specify storage engine
persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage });

export default store;
```

At your app's entry point,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Router from "./Router";
import store from './store';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />  // navigator
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, your API logic.

```
// action creator
export storePhoto = photos => {
    return {
        type: 'STORE_PHOTOS',
        payload: photos
    }
}

// photos reducer
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STORE_PHOTOS:
      return { ...state, photos: action.payload }
  // this is where `redux-persist` handles caching
    case REHYDRATE:
      var incoming = action.payload;
      if(incoming) return { ...state, ...incoming }
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

To retrieve data, you will see that redux abstracts away all the excess logics and there is no more `setItem, getItem` because `redux-persist` does that automagically for your already.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { storePhotos } from "./actions";

class GalleryList extends Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        const photos = await axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
        storePhoto(photos)
    }

    renderPhoto = ({ item }) => <GalleryDetail photo={item}/>

    keyExtractor = (photo, index) => photo.id;

    render () {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data = {this.props.photos}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this.renderPhoto}
            />
        );
    }
}

// pull data from photos reducer
const mapStateToProps = ({ photos }) => {
    return {
        photos: photos.photos
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { storePhotos })(GalleryList);
```

To summarise,

1. Install redux-persist in you project.
2. Import persistStore and autoRehydrate form redux-persist.
3. Add autoRehydrate to your store.
4. Pass your store to persistStore.
5. Listen to the persist/REHYDRATE action on your reducer and populate state accordingly.

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: I already use redux-persist, it's very cool, but what about cache expiration time ?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

### Caching the data for a specific period of time

```
const cacheIntervaInHours = 24
const cacheExpiryTime = new Date()
cacheExpiryTime.setHours(cacheExpiryTime.getHours() + cacheIntervalInHours)
const lastRequest = await AsyncStorage.getItem("lastRequest")

if (lastRequest == null || lastRequest > cacheExpiryTime) {
        fetch(`${apiUrl}/blogPosts/recent`)
        .then(async (response) => {
            return await response.json()
        })
        .then(async (json) => {
             if (!json || json.length == 0) {
                 throw new Error()
             }
            AsyncStorage.setItem("lastRequest", new Date());
            return await AsyncStorage.setItem('blogPosts', JSON.stringify(json))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
}
```

Comment: Caching the data for a specific period of time